# Is try catch required for simple CRUD operation in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, error-handling

I am less familiar with error handling and my question is different from usually I asked so please guide me if I am wrong. Sample of my CRUD operation:

```
User::where('active', true)->get(); // index method

User::where('role', 'admin')->first(); // show method

User::create($request->validated()); // store method

$user->update($request->validated()); // update method

$user->delete(); // destroy method
```

I have a project of Laravel containing following things:

1. One database (12 - 15 tables)
2. Model (6 - 8 Models)
3. CRUD Controller (for each model)
4. View (index/create/edit for each model)
5. Middleware ( 5 - 7 user roles)
6. FormRequest (store/update for each model)
7. Observer ( for each model to clearing cache items)
8. Policy ( for each model to check user based role permissions)
9. Event & Listeners (default/in-built)
10. Without API & external package installed

**Do I need to enclosed try/catch block to each part of my CRUD operation ?**

```
try {
    User::where('active', true)->get(); // index method

    User::where('role', 'admin')->first(); // show method

    User::create($request->validated()); // store method

    $user->update($request->validated()); // update method

    $user->delete(); // destroy method

} catch (\Throwable $th) {

    return to_route('home')->with('alert', alert('Error!', "Something went wrong",'error'));

}
```

**Or, if something goes wrong in the DB, Laravel will handle it.**

Comment: You don't _need_ try/catch at all if you don't want, you can let the error bubble. try/catch is useful if you want to try and recover from the error and continue execution afterwards, or to run some extra code which is custom to that place in the application, before exiting gracefully. So basically, if each of your operations is completely independent and there's no logical dependency from one to the other, and in business terms it would ok for some to succeed and others to fail and you could still carry on, then it might make sense to try/catch each one individually.

Comment: Unless you query columns that don't exist or strange stuff like that, the first few of those methods will not throw exceptions. For eg assuming you have an `active` col in your user table, `->get()` will just return an empty collection if nothing matches.  `->first()` will just return `null`.   If you're doing basic queries on columns you know exist there's no need to worry about exceptions. Of course if your database is gone or the password doesn't work that's a different story :-)

Answer (score 0):

You still have to add a try catch because we can't predict an exception. You certainly don't want when there is an exception the system displays an error page instead of giving notifications to the user.